# Drupal root not found on multisite setup after upgrading Drush 10 to 11/12

Tags: drush, upgrading, 10

This is a (25 sites) multisite setup running smoothly on Drupal 9.4 with Drush 10.x still.
Upgrading to Drupal 10.1.x and Drush 11 or 12 however makes Drush unusable.

Dir layout as installed by drupal/core-recommended:

```
/var/www/projectroot/
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── config
│   └── mysite.com
├── vendor
│   ├── asm89
│   │   └── stack-cors
│   ├── behat
│   │   ├── mink
│   │   ├── mink-browserkit-driver
│   │   └── mink-goutte-driver
│   ├── bin
│       └── drush
│   ├── bjeavons
│   │   └── drupal-finder
│   ├── drush
│   │   └── drush
│   │       ├── appveyor.yml
:   :       :
│   │       ├── drush
│   │       └── drush.bat
:   :
│   └── wikimedia
│       └── composer-merge-plugin
└── web
    ├── libraries
    ├── modules
    │   ├── contrib
    │   └── custom
    ├── profiles
    ├── robots.txt
    ├── sites
    │   ├── default
    │   └── mysite.com
    │       ├── files
    │       ├── services.yml
    │       └── settings.php
    ├── sites.php
    ├── themes
    │   └── mytheme
    ├── update.php
    └── web.config
```

`:` denotes items I think that are not relevant are left out.
The vendor directory is actually much bigger:

```
$ find vendor | wc -l
41837
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "myproject",
    "description": "myproject",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
        "drupal/admin_feedback": "^2.2",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "*",
        "drupal/allowed_formats": "^1.3",
        "drupal/animated_gif": "^2.0",
        "drupal/asset_injector": "^2.7",
        "drupal/better_passwords": "2.x",
        "drupal/block_content_machine_name": "dev-3286263-automated-drupal-10 as 3.0.2",
        "drupal/bootstrap_barrio": "^5.1",
        "drupal/ckeditorheight": "^1.8",
        "drupal/config_split": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/config_update": "*",
        "drupal/cookies": "^1.0",
        "drupal/core": "10.1.*",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "10.1.*",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "10.1.*",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "10.1.*",
        "drupal/csv_importer": "^1.15",
        "drupal/draggableviews": "^1.2",
        "drupal/easy_breadcrumb": "^2.0",
        "drupal/editor_file": "*",
        "drupal/facets": "^2.0",
        "drupal/file_extractor": "^4",
        "drupal/fixed_block_content": "dev-3357439-ui-updating-to",
        "drupal/focal_point": "^2.0",
        "drupal/fontyourface": "^3.5",
        "drupal/glossify": "^2.0",
        "drupal/imce": "*",
        "drupal/libraries": "^4.0",
        "drupal/matomo": "^1.12",
        "drupal/menu_block": "*",
        "drupal/menu_breadcrumb": "*",
        "drupal/menu_item_role_access": "^2.0",
        "drupal/menu_trail_by_path": "*",
        "drupal/metatag": "^1.16",
        "drupal/migrate_plus": "^6.0",
        "drupal/migrate_process_url": "^2.0.x-dev",
        "drupal/migrate_tools": "^6.0",
        "drupal/override_node_options": "^2.6",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.12",
        "drupal/paragraphs_edit": "^2.0",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.3",
        "drupal/permissions_by_term": "^3.1",
        "drupal/restui": "^1.17",
        "drupal/search_api": "^1.11",
        "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^4.1",
        "drupal/sitemap": "^2.0",
        "drupal/smart_trim": "*",
        "drupal/svg_image": "^1.14",
        "drupal/term_csv_export_import": "^4.0",
        "drupal/toc_js": "^2.1",
        "drupal/tome": "1.8.*",
        "drupal/unique_field_ajax": "^2.0",
        "drupal/user_current_paths": "^2.0",
        "drupal/user_redirect": "^1.0",
        "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.0",
        "drupal/video_embed_wysiwyg": "^2.0",
        "drupal/views_ajax_history": "^1.2",
        "drupal/views_block_area": "^1.0",
        "drupal/viewsreference": "^2.0",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.0",
        "drush/drush": "^11",
        "http-interop/http-factory-guzzle": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.4",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
        "toc/toc": "*",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "behat/mink": "*",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
        "drupal/devel": "*",
        "mikey179/vfsstream": "~1.2",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.4"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "me",
            "email": "me@mysite.com"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8",
            "exclude": [ "drupal/search_api_meilisearch", "drupal/better_passwords", "drupal/block_content_machine_name", "drupal/fixed_block_content" ]
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "toc/toc",
                "version": "v0.3.2",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jgallen23/toc/greenkeeper/update-all/dist/toc.min.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@mygitserver:search_api_meilisearch"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://git.drupalcode.org/issue/better_passwords-3296626.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://git.drupalcode.org/issue/block_content_machine_name-3286263.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://git.drupalcode.org/issue/fixed_block_content-3357439.git"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "patches": {
            "drupal/core": {
                "Field options 'Rewrite results' and 'Link to the Content' applied together is not working as expected": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-11-12/views_link_trim-2600456-22.patch",
                "Add file-mime formatter and make it output icons": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-07-15/2907414-31.patch",
                "Large decimal number do not validate as they should": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2022-07-26/2230909-269.patch",
                "Fix unnecessary multiple settings updates in AJAX calls": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-05-12/2771361-42.patch",
                "Add a 'machine_name' widget for string field types with a UniqueField constraint": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2023-05-17/drupal-10-1x-machine-name-widget-2685749-116.patch"
            },
            "drupal/toc_js": {
                "Disable showing the ToC as a default": "patches/toc_js_per_node_default_off.diff",
                "Fix umlaut and trailing special char conversion in ToC": "patches/toc_js_umlaut_and_trailing_char_fix.patch"
            },
            "drupal/metatag": {
                "Unset link rel: shortlink, edit-form, version-history and revision, and meta name: Generator, MobileOptimized, HandheldFriendly, viewport from <head> https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/2735195": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-04-29/metatag-unset-2735195-59.patch"
            },
            "drupal/bootstrap_barrio": {
                "Add missing jquery.once dependency for affix.js (https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio/issues/3278329 and ../3366908) #9505-10": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2023-06-14/3366908-2.patch"
            },
            "drupal/webform": {
                "Fix broken result export with drush": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2023-01-26/3335851-4.patch"
            },
            "drupal/permissions_by_term": {
                "Fix content is not editable with 3.1.22": "https://git.drupalcode.org/project/permissions_by_term/-/merge_requests/20.patch"
            },
            "drupal/facets": {
                "Facets with AJAX not working": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2023-02-07/facets-with-ajax-not-working-in-most-of-situations-3052574-174.patch"
            }
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "./web"
            }
        },
        "enable-patching": true,
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [ "type:drupal-core" ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "web/drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        },
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "web/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"
            ]
        }
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    }
}
```

As suggested in the comments, I reduced this to a minimum viable setup:

```
{
    "name": "myproject",
    "description": "myproject",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "drupal/core": "*",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "*",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "*",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "*",
        "drush/drush": "*"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "me",
            "email": "me@mysite.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "./web"
            }
        },
        "enable-patching": true,
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [ "type:drupal-core" ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "web/drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
        },
            "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "web/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"
            ]
        }
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    }
}
```

After this, I ran `composer update` (as the recommended `composer update "drupal/core-*" -W` would not update drupal/core as it was still locked to 9.4.x).
Still no joy.

On Drupal 9.4 and Drush 10.x, I was able to just use `drush -l mysite.com` when in /var/www/projectroot (or somewhere below, as well).

Now, no matter the CWD, I cannot for the life of me get drush to output meaningful stuff.

`user@webserver:/var/www/projectroot/web $ ../vendor/drush/drush/drush --root=sites/mysite.com`
or
`user@webserver:/var/www/projectroot $ vendor/bin/drush --root=web/sites/mysite.com`
or any other parameter combination with `-l` or `--url` or using absolute paths does not yield anything meaningful.
With drush 11 I get
`! [NOTE] Drupal root not found. Pass --root or a @siteAlias in order to see Drupal-specific commands.`

With is really strange, as drush seems to find the root (last line):

```
user@webserver:/var/www/projectroot $ vendor/bin/drush st
PHP binary    : /usr/bin/php8.1
PHP config    : /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
PHP OS        : Linux
PHP version   : 8.1.21
Drush script  : /var/www/projectroot/vendor/bin/drush
Drush version : 11.6.0
Drush temp    : /tmp
Drush configs : /var/www/projectroot/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
Drupal root   : /var/www/projectroot/web
```

Drush is installed via composer, as per the docs.

Drush 12 only gives me:
`The alias  references a Drupal site that does not contain its own copy of Drush. Please add Drush to this site to use it.`
(Note the double blank after alias; I consider this a bug, the error message should be different when a variable is undefined).
I can get similar output to Drush 11 if I use `@none` as an alias.

I don't need aliases and only want to use drush locally on this dev-server. Deployment has its own automatic framework.

Do I need a copy of drush in every multisite's `sites/<sitename>` dir?
I know global drush is not supported anymore, I switched from a system-wide installed drush to one in my project dir installed via composer (like it is still now) back at Drupal 8 and consider this locally installed, but I may be wrong?
If so, how?

Happy to provide more debug info if needed.

Thanks in advance for anyone taking a look at this!

Comment: There is almost nothing in the vendor directory.

Comment: How exactly did you upgrade? Can you post your composer.json, too?

Comment: Updated the description to make clear the vendor dir is actually much bigger. Added composer.json.
How did I upgrade?
I changed all occurences of `9.4.*` in `drupal/*` packages to `10.1.*` and ran `composer update -W`, fixing all the incompatible packages one by one by either increasing the version or using patches where no stable versions are available, yet.

Comment: I don’t think this is the present issue but that isn’t how it’s done.

Comment: I can try with the recommended `composer update "drupal/core-*" -W"` as per the manual, but this gets really involved as I cannot require and update in one go, which I need as the core update blocks the other packages and vice versa. (I want all versions to be pinned). I have to remove all the packages and re-add them again this way.
Did this, and will update the description. But as you said: It did not fix it.

Comment: I'm still stuck at this.
Trying to further reduce the possible errors, I tried with a fresh setup and .. drumroll .. same error!
Can anyone please try my minimum viable setup `composer.json` in my original post and issue `composer install` with it? It installs flawlessly, but drush is broken the same way it is when I upgrade my current install. There's either something inherently incompatible with my underlying OS/libs or my composer.json has an error I am unable to spot!

Comment: Progress!
A fresh install as per the installation instructions (without my composer.json) works, so it has to be something in composer.json. Diff'ed them.
`composer require "composer/installers": "^2.0"` makes drush work! Wouldn't this be very helpful to have as a dependency of core-recommended?

Comment: However, there's another issue:
Issuing `drush -l mysite.org st` does not give the correct site path. It is always `sites/default`. (Even if I pass `--root`, strange.)
This can be fixed by adding `$sites['mysite.org'] = 'mysite.org';` to `web/sites/sites.php`.
Under Drupal 8 and 9, I had no `sites.php` as somehow the default of having directories like the corresponding URLs was enough.
My question now is this: Is any of the issues I had a bug or are they features? How can we make sure other people find this out more quickly than (me) by debugging drush & friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with `composer.json` needing another require statement for some version between 9.4 and 10.1, most likely >=10.x.

This fixed all mentioned drush issues regarding `! [NOTE] Drupal root not found. Pass --root or a @siteAlias in order to see Drupal-specific commands.` or `The alias  references a Drupal site that does not contain its own copy of Drush. Please add Drush to this site to use it.`:

`composer require "composer/installers" "^2.0"`

Now, if you have a multisite setup that has worked on Drupal 8 and 9 without a `web/sites/sites.php` file (like me) and just using subdirectories that are called the same way as their URL, it seems you now have to explicitly define them in `web/sites/sites.php` (instantiate it using `example.sites.php`; just add `$sites['mysite.org'] = 'mysite.org';` for every multisite).

Without that, my drush 12.1 + Drupal 10.1 were not able to correctly determine the site path (always set to `sites/default` when issuing `drush -l mysite.org st`).

Make sure your `composer.json` looks as similar as possible to the one you get with a fresh install as outlined in the official docs, currently at https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/starting-a-site-using-drupal-composer-project-templates.
This helped me pinpoint the differences.

I consider this a bug in drush, there should be some check whether the needed packages are installed before failing in a way that does not give users a clue a package is missing.

The `sites.php` that is now needed should probably be part of the Drupal >=10.x release notes. If anyone knows how to disable the necessity for this, please chime in! This is an additional step in multisite creation/instantiation that is unnecessary imho, if there are no aliases/ports needed. It would be nice to have this as default again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this but in my case the issue was I was using Docker, where I encountered this error: "Composer plugins have been disabled for safety in this non-interactive session. Set COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 if you want to allow plugins to run as root/super user". Adding "COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1" to my Dockerfile solved it. Hope it helps someone